# Extjs 4: How to access a class by name in a string variable

Tags: class, extjs, static, extjs4

How to access a class by name in a string variable?
I don't want to instantiate it, only want to access its static variables.
The name is always changing, it's an incoming parameter of a function.

I have something like this:

```
function someFunction (className)
{
    var myClass = *theFuncToAccessClass*(className);
    alert(myClass.staticVariable);
}
```

So I'm searching for the *theFuncToAccessClass* .
Is it possible somehow?

Comment: Can you give an example for `className` ?

Comment: Example: 'FilmFeszt.controller.User'

Answer (score 6):

It's [`Ext.ClassManager#get`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.ClassManager-method-get).

Example:

```
var Clazz = Ext.ClassManager.get(className);
```

**Update** Ensuring the class is loaded

```
Ext.require(className, function(Clazz) {
    // the callback will be passed a reference to the class constructor,
    // so you won't even need to resolve it with the ClassManager now...
    Clazz.staticProperty
});
```

Comment: Do I have to load it before somehow, or Ext.js knows where it is by the name convention? By reading the manual-reference, this should work, but now it's result is null or undefined.

I can istantiate it without previously loading or requiring it - that works.

Comment: You're right, the function just does a lookup in already loaded classes, so you must require it somehow before this can work. You should wrap this code with a require call (I'm updating my answer with an example of what I mean).